# Image generation for point-cloud data using generative ML models

Tags: deep-learning, generative-models

I have a dataset containing 3D point-cloud image data, ie I have four coordinates, x,y,z and Intensity. I am tasked with coming up with a generative model that produces new images based on the dataset.

It's not very clear how I would feed my model data of this kind. I know that I can flatten an image into an array and feed it in if I had a grid-type situation but I don't know how to translate that in the case of a point-cloud. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Never done it. But this [podcast](https://twimlai.com/twiml-talk-123-semantic-segmentation-3d-point-clouds-lyne-tchapmi/) had a guest that did exactly this. Might be useful to listen to the podcast, and check out her research for more resources.